# Ammeter showing wrong value

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter, schematic

I am trying to figure out why the multimeter is not displaying the right current.

I purchased a [bayite DC 6.5-100V 0-100A LCD display digital current voltage power energy meter multimeter ammeter voltmeter with 100A current shunt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013PKYILS) and connected it according to the instructions.

It is connected to a water pump circuit with a 12V marine battery as the power source.

The voltage reading seems right (~12-13V).  When the 12V water pump is off, and a relay in the circuit is energized, the current reading is 1.33A but the specifications for the relay says the current draw when the coil is energized is ~160mA.

When the water pump is on, the reading is 138A.  The pump specifications says the maximum current draw is 17A.  I have a 20A fuse connected to the pump.

If it was drawing 138A, the fuse should have blown long ago.

When the meter is showing 1.33A with just a relay active, an inline measurement using a multimeter shows 120 mA draw, which is what I would expect.

The meter is connected according to the instructions via the provided external shunt.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome! Most probably miswired. Do you see that the schematic is upside down and that the shunt is on the negative terminal?

Comment: Is the shunt marked 75mV/100A? What voltage do  you measure across the shunt? Probably you have wired it incorrectly.

Comment: Or it's off by a decimal place. Connect a known ~1 A load, e.g.,, R264 or R267 dome lamp, or 12 Ω resistor and see if it shows 10.0 A, rather than 1.00 A. Thanks, @jsotola, for correction.

Comment: Can you post a photo of your setup showing how you wired it?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  I wired it according to the documentatio.  When looking at the backside of the meter, the top terminal goes to the negative of the load and the shunt.  The bottom wire (red) goes to the + terminal of the battery (and the + side of the load). The shunt measured 0.01V drop and the meter is configured for 100A because the shunt is suppose to be 100A.  When only the relay is active, the meter measures 1.33A.  I put a multimeter in line from the + battery to the side of the shunt for the "red wire".   the multimeter reads 120 mA, which is what I expected.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to upload an image - is that possible here?

Comment: I have the same issue on mine too. Shows 1/3 the actual amperage. This seems to be an issue with this meter. Is there a setting in the configuration to recalibrate it? There is only one button and no manual. I’ve pushed the button in every conceivable manner, but I am flying blind and don’t seem to get very far, except to set the voltage alarm range.

Comment: @SidC - Hi, Re: "*Trying to figure out how to upload an image - is that possible here?*" Yes. Click [Edit] below your question to start the edit process. Then either click the "mountains" icon, or press Ctrl+G on a PC keyboard, to bring up a dialog offering options to upload an image from the PC/mobile device's local filesystem, or copy it from a URL, or copy it from the clipboard. || If you get stuck following the process, you can either ask here (flag your own question if you need mod help) or ask a question on [Meta] where it's easier to do support, without the constraints of comments.